# Plotting 'partial' dashed lines along selected intervals for a curve represented by any arbitrary function

Tags: plotting

I have

`fixedpoint = x /. Solve[f[x] == x && -1 <= f[x] <= 1, x]`

The stability of the fixed points are governed by the absolute value of the derivative of the map wrt the position variable and evaluated at the fixed point; stable for <1 and unstable for >1

`Reduce[Abs[D[f[x], x] /. x -> fixedpoint[[1]]] < 1]`

`Reduce[Abs[D[f[x], x] /. x -> fixedpoint[[1]]] > 1]`

`Reduce[Abs[D[f[x], x] /. x -> fixedpoint[[2]]] < 1, a]`

`Reduce[Abs[D[f[x], x] /. x -> fixedpoint[[2]]] < 1, a]`

`Reduce[Abs[D[f[x], x] /. x -> fixedpoint[[3]]] < 1, a]`

`Reduce[Abs[D[f[x], x] /. x -> fixedpoint[[3]]] > 1, a]`

The geometric plots are:

`Plot[{fixedpoint[[1]], fixedpoint[[2]], fixedpoint[[3]]}, {a, -5, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"a=0", 
   "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(-Sqrt[a - 2]\), \(Sqrt[a]\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(Sqrt[a - 2]\), \(Sqrt[a]\)]\)"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"a", "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(*\)]\)(a)"}]`

Say, for the function x=0 in the set of functions above, I would like to implement dashed lines on the interval between a<0 and a>2 but 'undashed' lines on the interval everywhere to signify the stabilities for the function x=0.
The Wolfram documentation provides a brute force implementation of dashed lines for a single curve but having selected regions of the curves for which dashed lines can be implemented might require some tricks.

How can this be done?

Comment: `Show` differently styled plots for different domains.

Comment: `Show` has a second argument "option". What is the form for "option"? Is there more I can read up on?

Comment: I don't understand, have you read `Show` docs past the first line?

Comment: For any value between a = 0 and 2 Sqrt[a-2] is not Real. So it cannot be plotted using Plot directly. How do you intend to show the Dashed lines ? Dashed lines from where to where ?

Comment: @Lotus I was being sloppy with my words. I intend to show dashed lines for a<0 and a>2.
Editing OP

Comment: OP has been edited. Hopefully, it is now clearer.

Comment: Is the edit really needed? Can;t the problem be shown on e.g. `x^2`?

Comment: @Kuba of course you could. In fact, less hassle.